# how to acquire arduino ethercard udp receive data?

Tags: arduino, udp

I have a problem in accessing received udp string, I can get it by serial though. I just need to get my incoming udp data into a variable using the ethercard library in loop() function so I can use them in my program.Here's the code I'm working with:

```
#include <EtherCard.h>
#include <IPAddress.h>

#define STATIC 1  // set to 1 to disable DHCP (adjust myip/gwip values below)

#if STATIC
// ethernet interface ip address
static byte myip[] = { 192,168,1,200 };
// gateway ip address
static byte gwip[] = { 192,168,1,1 };
#endif

// ethernet mac address - must be unique on your network
static byte mymac[] = { 0x70,0x69,0x69,0x2D,0x30,0x31 };
byte Ethernet::buffer[500]; // tcp/ip send and receive buffer
//callback that prints received packets to the serial port
void udpSerialPrint(word port, byte ip[4], const char *data, word len) {
  Serial.println(data);
}

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(57600);
  Serial.println("\n[backSoon]");

  if (ether.begin(sizeof Ethernet::buffer, mymac, 10) == 0)
    Serial.println( "Failed to access Ethernet controller");
#if STATIC
  ether.staticSetup(myip, gwip);
#else
  if (!ether.dhcpSetup())
    Serial.println("DHCP failed");
#endif

  ether.printIp("IP:  ", ether.myip);
  ether.printIp("GW:  ", ether.gwip);
  ether.printIp("DNS: ", ether.dnsip);

  //register udpSerialPrint() to port 1337
  ether.udpServerListenOnPort(&udpSerialPrint, 1337);

  //register udpSerialPrint() to port 42.
  ether.udpServerListenOnPort(&udpSerialPrint, 42);
}

void loop(){
  //this must be called for ethercard functions to work.
  ether.packetLoop(ether.packetReceive());

  //? incoming = data; <--- this is my problem
  //Serial.println(incoming);

}
```

It's just a slightly modified version of the UDPListener example that comes with the ethercard library. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still on a steep learning curve myself but have managed to get UDP talking between units so hope following helps.  Suspect the quickest way would be to create a global variable such as:

char gUDPdata[30] = "";

then in your udpSerialPrint routine add the following for a quick and dirty result. This copies 'data' to a global variable that you can see in your main loop.

```
Serial.println(data);
data[0] = 0;
strcpy(data, gUDPdata);
```

then in your main loop following should produce same as Serial.print in the udpSerialPrint routine.

```
Serial.println(gUDPdata);
```